# Software package to support cabinet design

Tags: server, hardware, visual-design, electronics, component-diagram

I am looking for a software package to support the design and build of rack mounted servers/cabinets.

It must be able to:

- Visually represent the server/cabinet and it's contents
- Allow for interconnectivity diagrams to be made
- Store information about the hardware and it's configuration

It would be running on Microsoft Windows 7. Price isn't an issue as long as I can justify it to my business unit.

Any information or reccomendations would be greatly appreciated.